# Javascript not running "else" or "===" but works for "if" and "else if"

Tags: javascript

Hello I'm new to javascript and trying to run the following

```
var age = prompt("What is your age");
if (age < 19) {
  document.write("You can't drink");
}
else if (age === 19) {
  document.write("you can finally drink");
}
else (age > 19) {
  document.write("you can already drink");
}
```

I can't seem to get anything to show up but if I change my code to remove the else statement and change the `===` to just `==` my code runs. This is how it looks like when it runs after I get rid of the else statement and `===` operator.

```
var age = prompt("What is your age");
if (age < 19) {
  document.write("You can't drink");
}    
else if (age == 19) {
  document.write("you can finally drink");
}
```

I'm trying to get the first block of code to run but can't. The page is empty and no prompt shows up. Someone please help.

Comment: `else (age > 19)` doesnt make much sense, else is when all if and else if are false, you dont need any condition.

Comment: There is no condition in an else branch, it's simply ignored. See [*The if Statement*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-if-statement), the (simplified) form is: `if (expression) { statement } else { statement }`.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few mistakes in your code:

**1)** `prompt` method return `string` no `number`, so :

Use `==` instead of `===` :

```
else if (age == 19) {
```

PS: (19 == '19'); is `true`  **but** (19 === '19'); is `false`

**OR** convert `age` to number :

```
else if (Number(age) === 19) {
```

**2)** You should not use condition for `else` , so you must change `else` like this:

```
else { document.write("you can already drink"); }
```

```js
var age = prompt("What is your age");

if (age < 19) { document.write("You can't drink"); }

else if (Number(age) === 19) { document.write("you can finally drink"); }

else { document.write("you can already drink"); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the last else statement. You are putting a condition after the else, which does not work. You only add the condition after another if. You can fix this by removing the condition like so:

```
var age = prompt("What is your age");
if (age < 19) {
  document.write("You can't drink");
}
else if (age === 19) {
  document.write("you can finally drink");
}
else {
  document.write("you can already drink");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to understant differnce between "==" and "===" . From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523643/difference-between-and-in-javascript) you can conclude

> JavaScript has both strict and type-converting equality comparison. For strict equality the objects being compared must have the same type and:
>   Two strings are strictly equal when they have the same sequence of characters, same length, and same characters in corresponding positions.
>   Two numbers are strictly equal when they are numerically equal (have the same number value). NaN is not equal to anything, including NaN. Positive and negative zeros are equal to one another.
>   Two Boolean operands are strictly equal if both are true or both are false.
>   Two objects are strictly equal if they refer to the same Object.
>   Null and Undefined types are == (but not ===). [I.e. (Null==Undefined) is true but (Null===Undefined) is false]

And secondly "else" with a condition is always written as "else if" ...else is block which is runs when none of its above conditions is true i.e none is true ..read from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/Js/js_if_else.asp) for more information

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be having some logical error in your last `else` statement. If none of the first 2 conditions are true, then logically speaking, the last condition must be true. `else` does not hold any conditions. It's simply just *else* in terms of the previous condition(s). Else you would have to use `else if()` again, but as mentioned earlier, in case neither of the conditions are true, then the last condition must be the case regardless in this example. Therefore, just *else* makes the most sense.

Example:

```
if (age < 19) {
  document.write("You can't drink");
}
else if (age === 19) {
  document.write("you can finally drink");
}
else {
  document.write("you can already drink");
}
```

Another thing in terms of your operators. `==` means equal to, and can be used to compare different *types*. I.e. you can compare a *number* type to a *string* type, and if they both hold the same value, the statement will be true. However, `===` is a strict equals, and means that the things being compared must be the same value AND the same type.

Example:

```
var x = 5; //number
var y = '5'; //string

if(x == y) {
    //true, because they are equal, both has the value 5
}

if(x === y) {
    //false, because even though they are equal in value, they are not the same type
}

var a = 8; //number
var b = 8; //number

if(a === b) {
    //true, because they are both equal, and the same type
}
```

So, to clearify,

`==` checks if the values are *equal*, no matter the *type*.

`===` checks if the values are *equal* AND are of the same *type*.

More simple documentation on operators [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_operators.asp).